# Limit display multidimensional array to page navigation php

Tags: php, arrays, pagination

how to limit display multidimensional array for navigation

if visitor page 1 will display

first 1 2 3 4 .. 509 last

if page 2

first 2 3 4 5 .. 509 last

if page 398

first 396 397 398 399 .. 509 last

if page 509

first 1 .. 506 507 508 509 last

how can I do that

thanks for advice

```
[MyProduct] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [id] => 1
                [1] => Title 1
                [title] => Title 1
                [2] => Post 1
                [post] => Post 1
                [6] => post-1
                [url] => post-1
                [18] => 81000
                [price] => 81000
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2
                [id] => 2
                [1] => Title 2
                [title] => Title 2
                [2] => Post 2
                [post] => Post 2
                [6] => post-2
                [url] => post-2
                [18] => 75000
                [price] => 75000
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3
                [id] => 3
                [1] => Title 3
                [title] => Title 3
                [2] => Post 3
                [post] => Post 3
                [6] => post-3
                [url] => post-3
                [18] => 37000
                [price] => 37000
            )

        ... and more array ...

        [510] => Array
            (
                [0] => 509
                [id] => 509
                [1] => Title 509
                [title] => Title 509
                [2] => Post 509
                [post] => Post 509
                [6] => post-509
                [url] => post-509
                [18] => 69000
                [price] => 69000
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please get rid of this multidimensional array and get an integer instead which tells you how many pages there are. What happens if you get to 10.000 pages? You're going to run out of memory. The way I'd do this:

Create a piece of code that has some scenario's:

1. user is in the middle of the pages (e.g. 4-300)
2. user is in the beginning of the pages (e.g. 1-4)
3. user is in the end of the pages (e.g. 301-305)

It's fairly easy to write a piece of code for each scenario that shows the links to the appropriate pages, as long as you keep it separate.

edit:

some example code, there are no links but you get the idea

```
$current_page = 5; 
$pages = 100; // number of pages

// beginning
if ($current_page < 7) {
   echo implode(' ', range(1,10));
   echo '..';
   echo implode(' ', range($pages-3, $pages));
}
// end
else if ($current_page > $pages-7) {
   echo implode(' ', range(1,3));
   echo '..';
   echo implode(' ', range($pages-10, $pages));
}
// middle 
else {
   echo implode(' ', range(1,2));
   echo '..';
   echo implode(' ', range($current_page-2, $current_page+2)); 
   echo '..';
   echo implode(' ', range($pages-1, $pages));
}
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of how to do it? Bram